# Reindex time-stamped data with date_range

Tags: python, time-series, pandas, data-analysis

I have a `pandas.Series` of time-stamped data - basically a sequence of events:

```
0      2012-09-05 19:28:52
1      2012-09-05 19:28:52
2      2012-09-05 19:44:37
3      2012-09-05 19:44:37
4      2012-09-05 20:04:53
5      2012-09-05 20:04:53
6      2012-09-05 20:12:59
7      2012-09-05 20:13:15
8      2012-09-05 20:13:15
9      2012-09-05 20:13:15
```

I'd like to create a `pandas.TimeSeries` over a specific `pandas.date_range` (e.g. 15min interval; `pandas.date_range(start, end, freq='15T')`) which holds the count of events for each period. How can this be accomplished?

thanks, 
 Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would use the timestamps of the events as index of the series instead of the data, resample can do this. In the example below, the index of series s are the timestamps and data is the event_id, basically the index of your series.

```
In [47]: s
Out[47]:
                      event_id
timestamp
2012-09-05 19:28:52          0
2012-09-05 19:28:52          1
2012-09-05 19:44:37          2
2012-09-05 19:44:37          3
2012-09-05 20:04:53          4
2012-09-05 20:04:53          5
2012-09-05 20:12:59          6
2012-09-05 20:13:15          7
2012-09-05 20:13:15          8
2012-09-05 20:13:15          9
```

*resample* (this method can also be used on a DataFrame) will give a new series  with in this case 15min periods, the end time of a bucket (period) is used to refer to it (you can control this with the *label* arg).

```
In [48]: s.resample('15Min', how=len)
Out[48]:
                      event_id
timestamp
2012-09-05 19:30:00          2
2012-09-05 19:45:00          2
2012-09-05 20:00:00          0
2012-09-05 20:15:00          6
```

Comment: Definitely pay attention to the `closed` and `label` options to `resample`!